# Removing new lines (\n\n) from start of paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a paragraph that I'm fetching from ChatGPT, however it's adding two new lines at the start of the paragraph. Is there a way/regex I can use to remove those somehow?

Comment: See [`String.prototype.trimStart()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart)

Comment: `chatString.trim()` will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex `.replace(/^\s+/, '')`, or simply `.trim()`:

```js
const input = '\n\r\n\rSome text.';
console.log('input:"', input, '"');
const result1 = input.replace(/^\s+/, '');
console.log('result1:"', result1, '"');
const result2 = input.trim();
console.log('result2:"', result2, '"');
```

Not that this also takes into account Windows-style `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: Trim! That's what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This regex will replace all new line chars from the beginning of your text:

`/^\n+/`

Comment: Safer to use `str.replace(/^\s+/, '')` to catch also `\r`, or simply use `str.trim()`